# What data type can I use instead of 'var' in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, var

```
var x = new something();
```

I tried to make that but Eclipse says

> var cannot be resolved to a type

What type can I use in Java 8?

Comment: Java 10 has var type. https://dzone.com/articles/finally-java-10-has-var-to-declare-local-variables

Comment: If you need var in java 8 try Project Lombok https://projectlombok.org/features/var

Comment: lombok enables that in Java 8. Very handy small library

Comment: None of the answers good enough to accept?

Answer (score 4):

Both of the following should work:

- `Something x = new Something();`
- `Object x = new Something();`

In addition to `Something` and `Object`, you should be able to use any class that `Something` extends from, or any interface that `Something` implements (either directly or indirectly).

---

<sup>Probably a good idea to start reading up on how the Java type system works.</sup>

Comment: It's extremely likely that `Object x = new Something();` will *not* work, because the following code that needs to use the value cannot access any methods added by type `Something`.

Comment: @Andreas Granted, but I don't see any following code in the question, and I have no information about the actual types being used. For all I know, it would be cleaner to declare the variable as some interface type that I'm unaware of. Best possible advice that I can give to OP: read up on the Java type system and take it from there.

Comment: *"I have no information about the actual types being used"* Sure you do, the code uses the `Something` type. --- *"I don't see any following code in the question"* True, but the only reason for assigning to a variable is for later code to use the value. What you see in the question is a snippet, but we are allowed to infer at least a little about the context. --- *"cleaner to declare the variable as some interface type"* Agreed, but `Object` is not it. --- I not disagreeing with the rest of your answer, but it is *extremely likely* that `Object` will not work as a replacement for `var`.

Answer (score 3):

The `var` keyword was added in Java 10, and tells the compiler to infer the type from the value on the right side of the `=` assignment operator.

Which means that the following are equivalent, i.e. the compiler will generate the exact same bytecode:

```
var x = new something();

something x = new something();
```

---

*FYI:* `something` is a type (class, interface, enum), and Java naming convention is for type names to start with uppercase letter, so it should be named `Something`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Without var**
    String str = "Chaman Bharti";
    String substring = str.substring(7);
    System.out.println(substring);//Bharti
    System.out.println(substring.getClass().getTypeName());//java.lang.String
```

var is used to reduce boiler code in above line I have used String RHS(Right Hand Side) two times whereas in below line I have not  used because Compiler infer according to assigned value of LHS(Left Hand Side).

```
    **With var**
    var str = "Chaman Bharti";
    var substring = str.substring(7);
    System.out.println(substring);//Bharti
    System.out.println(substring.getClass().getTypeName());//java.lang.String
```

Comment: So the only benefit of using "var" is that you don't have to enter a type on the assignment, and you lose the ability to easily identify the type other than through deriving it from the right-side of the assignment.

I'm not really seeing any plus there, and from a maintenance point of view, makes it a bit harder to debug code.